# H2 database Unsuccessful schema statement when add index and foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, hibernate, h2

H2 does not appear to support the index/FK syntax generated by hibernate for the MySQL5 dialects when using ;MODE=MYSQL and hibernate with a dialect of org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect.

My goal here is to have one set of SQL scripts and use hibernate for the ORM parts. Everything works fine in MySQL 5.5 but when I try to use H2 for things like unit tests and starting up a demo version of my app I get hundreds of failures from hibernate generated alter table statements as shown below. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a way to get hibernate to change the way the statements are generated but that might be an option as well. I tried using org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect but that produces more severe errors so I don't think that will work.

```
alter table SAM_PUBLISHEDSECUREDIP_T
  add index FK1EDEA25B9482C945 (ASSESSMENTID), 
  add constraint FK1EDEA25B9482C945 foreign key (ASSESSMENTID) 
  references SAM_PUBLISHEDASSESSMENT_T (ID)
```

Results in an error like this in H2:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER
>   TABLE SAM_PUBLISHEDSECUREDIP_T ADD INDEX FK1EDEA25B9482C945
>   (ASSESSMENTID),[*] ADD CONSTRAINT FK1EDEA25B9482C945 FOREIGN KEY
>   (ASSESSMENTID) REFERENCES SAM_PUBLISHEDASSESSMENT_T (ID) "; SQL
>   statement:  alter table SAM_PUBLISHEDSECUREDIP_T add index
>   FK1EDEA25B9482C945 (ASSESSMENTID), add constraint FK1EDEA25B9482C945
>   foreign key (ASSESSMENTID) references SAM_PUBLISHEDASSESSMENT_T (ID)
>   [42000-172]

NOTE: I am open to writing and providing a patch for H2 but I could use some tips on where to look in that codebase.

Comment: You wrote: "I tried using org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect but that produces more severe errors". What error did it produce? If ever possible, you should use the H2 dialect with the H2 database.

Comment: Here are a few examples of failing SQL when I set it in H2Dialect:
(1) Column "TABLE_ROWS" not found; SQL statement:
select TABLE_ROWS FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='BLAH' ORDER BY CREATE_TIME LIMIT 1; [42122-172]
(2) Syntax error in SQL statement " ALTER TABLE BLAH ADD  ( PRIMARY[*] KEY (REALM_KEY, NAME) ) "; expected "identifier";
(3) Syntax error in SQL statement "SHOW COLUMNS FROM CONTENT_RESOURCE LIKE[*] 'FILE_SIZE'
(4) Value too long for column "IS_DURABLE VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL": "'FALSE' (5)";

Comment: As far as I can see, those queries are not created by either the MySQLDialect nor the H2Dialect. Do you run them explicitly in your application ("native SQL statements")? When in this case you need to use MySQL, as H2 does not support those. Because _only_ MySQL supports them (no other database).

Comment: That's correct Thomas. These are written for MySQL. That's why I am trying to use the H2 MYSQL mode for these and running into the issue with the hibernate generated SQL above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

H2 is not 100% compatible with MySQL, even when using the MySQL mode. It seems some of your SQL statements are not supported by H2.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an index is not done using `alter table` (does MySQL really use this strange syntax? Every DBMS I know uses `CREATE INDEX` to create an index).

You have to split this up in two statements:

```
CREATE INDEX fk_assessment_id_index 
     on SAM_PUBLISHEDSECUREDIP_T (ASSESSMENTID);

alter table SAM_PUBLISHEDSECUREDIP_T
  add constraint FK1EDEA25B9482C945 foreign key (ASSESSMENTID) 
  references SAM_PUBLISHEDASSESSMENT_T (ID);
```

Those two statements should also work in MySQL if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Unfortunately this syntax is being generated by Hibernate and I don't have any control over it (that I have been able to figure out anyway). If I could simply change the code I would definitely do that. If you have a solution to convince hibernate to generate the saner syntax you mention that would be awesome but otherwise I think I am still stuck.

Comment: @azeckoski: then this is clearly a but in Hibernate if it creates invalid DDL for H2